# Which mobile browsers for testing?

Tags: mobile, testing

I've mobile optimised a site with media queries and I now want to know which devices / emulators I should test with. Where can I find information on what mobile browsers are out there, ideally with a rough idea or market share?

So far I've tested with Opera Mobile (desktop version), iPhone and iPad (actual devices), Windows Phone (emulator) and I'm attempting to install the Android emulator but having some issues. I've Googled but couldn't find much info on BlackBerry devices, so I'm downloading their emulator too. Are there any I've missed out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Mobile browser market share

StatCounter offers a rough indication of mobile browser usage share in their [Top Mobile Browsers from Sept 2010 to Sept 2011](http://gs.statcounter.com/#mobile_browser-ww-monthly-201009-201109) chart, which Wikipedia has made sense of in [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers#StatCounter_Mobile).

Ranked from most to least popular:

1. iPhone + iPod Touch (22.84%)
2. Opera Mini (22.24%)
3. Android (20.21%)
4. Nokia (12.57%)
5. BlackBerry (9.51%)
6. [UC Browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UC_Browser) (4.71%)

#### Mobile browser emulators

As you rightly say, the best thing to do is test on actual devices where you can, but for the missing platforms you can try the following emulators ([full list here](http://www.mobilexweb.com/emulators)):

- To test the **iPhone**, **iPod Touch**, and **iPad**, you can download the iOS Simulator for Mac by [logging into your developer account](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action#downloads) (requires that you register a free account).
- To test **Opera Mini**, **Android**, the **UC Browser**, and others—such as Firefox—you can download the [Android Emulator.](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
- To test **Nokia's** browsers, you can download the [S40](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/cc48f9a1-f5cf-447b-bdba-c4d41b3d05ce/Series_40_Platform_SDKs.html) and [S60](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/ec866fab-4b76-49f6-b5a5-af0631419e9c/S60_All_in_One_SDKs.html) emulators.
- To test the **BlackBerry** browser, you can download the [BlackBerry simulator](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/simulators.jsp).

#### An alternative to local emulation

You may also wish to keep an eye on [BrowserStack,](http://www.browserstack.com/) the web-based browser testing suite, who mentioned by email that they're working on support for mobile browser testing:

> We received more than 50 feature requests, few have been implemented
> and the major ones on which we are currently working are:
>
> - Browsers on Mac & Linux Operating Systems
> - High Responsive Live Testing
> - Mobile Platform Browsers

If they're able to offer this, it would be much easier for web developers than having to download and update multiple emulators.