# Mobile browser statistics by versions?

Tags: mobile, usage-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What mobile browsers for testing?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20933/what-mobile-browsers-for-testing)

Where can I find more detailed mobile usage statistics so I know which devices to test on?

This link gives info by OS, but not by version. 
http://gs.statcounter.com/#mobile_os-ww-monthly-201009-201109

For instance in the UK BlackBerry is quite popular, but I don't know what age of device I don't need to test on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend looking at your own visitor statistics through free tools such as Google Analytics where you can easily dissect your hits by browser, OS, and browser version, as well as see the trends in how your visitors are changing. Even if you find an overall external source with "reliable" or "accurate" numbers your own site is likely attracting a subset of visitors that are not perfectly representative of overall statistics, whether due to geographic location, content, age or gender of most typical visitor, etc, which will all have an impact on what kind of devices are used to access your website.

Thus I recommend using the number of visitors to your site to come up with a personal threshold based on either numbers or percentage of hits from various browser versions. You might decide that if your visits from IE6 drop below 2% then you don't need to support it anymore. On the other hand, if you receive a million hits a day you might decide that 2% is still worth supporting, but you might go with a raw number and say any browser that sends less than 100 hits a day isn't worth supporting. The key is to come up with a reasonable metric based on your personal statistics and how many browsers you have the resources to test and develop for so you can find that proper balance between supporting everything under the sun and losing customers.

Comment: Im afraid that current traffic is too low for my analytics to be of any use.

Comment: Ah, ok... are you getting _any_ hits from mobile browsers at this time? Or are you looking for an up-to-date list of browsers that you are likely to receive hits from in the future? (It could be argued that mobile browsers are changing so fast that if you aren't receiving any hits from some of the older ones right now it not be worth testing for them at all.)

Comment: The site is only getting a few hits a day from mobile visitors, and they may be internal traffic anyway. Im looking to promote it more (its been a bit neglected), im getting about 100 total visitors a day. Its a brochure site for my services so even though the traffic is low its important that it looks professional to potential clients.

Answer (score 0):

[webmasterpro.de](http://www.webmasterpro.de/), a german website, has statistics for browsers in general and broken down to different versions:

http://www.webmasterpro.de/portal/webanalyse-aktuell.html

see the section about "Verbreitung verschiedener Browserversionen" - theres just one problem: this aren't only mobile browsers but all. and there are no browsers listed below 1% usage. the only mobile browsers i see there at the moment are:

- Mobile Safari 5.0 with 2.8%
- Android Browser 4.0 with 1.3%

that said, this might not be the best ressource for the information you need, but maybe it's useful anyway.

Comment: Good to know but doesnt really answer my question. Instead of the total Android Browser market share, id like to know what market share each version has. Then I can make a decision about how old browsers need to be before I wont support them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of providers of stats on mobiles, their market share and in which countries:

- [BuzzCity](http://www.buzzcity.com/f/reports) - insights into their ad network
- [Admob](http://metrics.admob.com) - data from their massive ad network (now Google Adsense which you should check out)
- [InMobi](http://www.inmobi.com/research/) - advertising network stats
- [Opera Mini](http://www.opera.com/smw/) - Handset coverage for many countries
- [GetJar](http://developer.getjar.com) - more stats from their download stats
- [OpenWave](http://www.openwave.com/solutions/data_mediation_and_analytics/multimedia.html) - Gateway provider's information
- [Akamai](http://www.akamai.com/stateoftheinternet/) - Worldwide network insights, not focussed on mobile like the above ones